# What does the colour green symbolise in the Maze Runner?

Tags: analysis, dialogue, the-maze-runner

I was watching the Maze Runner again and When Newt had called Thomas the *Greenbean*, what did he mean by this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The colour green symbolises new or fresh or inexperienced, what it means is that Thomas was new to the Glade and inexperienced. *Bean* is just a catchphrase to rhyme with *Green*.

Answer (score 0):

The colour green was used in comparison to Thomas being a 'newbie' and the bean bit was because that was the start of his journey when he arrived there. He grew from then on.